# Polymer Designer - Dart Port

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-designer-tool

Polymer recently unveiled an initial version of its GUI designer at http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/

However, all codes generated are in JavaScript.

Does Dart-polymer team plans to create a port that actually generates Dart code?
Thanks

Comment: I think you should add a feature request at dartbug.com/new. The Dart team will then post updates to this issue.

Comment: Will do Gunter. Thanks